# How to get the build project in TFS Custom build activitiy

Tags: c#, build, tfs

I am creating a custom build definition which I want to use to increment my assembly numbers on a check in. I followed [this blog](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/07/how-to-versioning-builds-with-tfs-2010.html) which states to pass in `Workspace` when changing the `ReadOnly` files. I have a source control structure like this:

- Team collaboration

  - Solution A

    - Project A
    - Project B
  - Solution B

    - Project A
    - Project B

I have set up my custom build for **Project B** in solution **B**. I have implemented a logger to log what actions are happening where for testing purposes using this code:

```
protected void TrackMessage(CodeActivityContext context, string message)
{
  context.Track(new BuildInformationRecord<BuildMessage>()
  {
    Value = new BuildMessage()
    {
      Message = message,
      Importance = BuildMessageImportance.High
    }
  });
}
```

Fundamentally, when I `override execute` I get:

```
Workspace workspace = context.GetValue<Workspace>(CurrentWorkspace);
foreach (WorkingFolder folder in workspace.Folders)
{
  TrackMessage(context, string.Format("Working Folder: {0}", folder.LocalItem));
  //Then get all directories for this working folder
}
```

My Working Folder comes out as `Team collaboration` which then gets all `AssemblyInfo.*` files within the whole collaboration project! I am at a loss as to what property I have to pass in and what type it is, I have tried researching it to find which property to use to get just `TeamCollaboration\Solution B\Project B` into my folder.

Any ideas on what type and property I am looking for to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can correct this issue by narrowing your working folder mappings within the `build configuration`.  Try setting it as follows:

- Edit Build Configuration
- Click on Source Settings (VS 2012), Workspace (VS 2010)
- Make your mappings look like this:

<kbd>Status</kbd><kbd>Source Control Folder</kbd>                 <kbd>Build Agent Folder</kbd>                
<kbd>Active</kbd><kbd>$/Team collaboration/Solution B</kbd>  <kbd>$(SourceDir)\</kbd>

This will make the workspace for this build be limited to the solution that you wish to build.  Therefore only AssemblyInfo files under that will be visible to your build activity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Was just about to post this answer! When I set the build, I thought the workspace would update but yeah it didn't. +1